# How to implement Uncle Bob's ideia of zero parameters in this case?

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, testing, tdd

I am trying to apply a principle I read on Uncle Bob's book "Clean Code", which states that the optimal amount of parameters for a method is zero. I found this is very hard to accomplish, but anyways here I am trying it and I'd like your help to understand the best way to come closer to it in my code.

So far, I have a controller and a simple service to do the job I want. My controller is implemented as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Cms;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\GroupRequest;
use App\Models\Group;
use App\Services\GroupsService;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class GroupsController extends Controller
{
  protected $group_service;

  public function __construct(GroupsService $group_service)
  {
    $this->group_service = $group_service;
  }

  public function index()
  {
    $groups = $this->group_service->listAll();

    return view('cms.groups.index', compact('groups'));
  }

  public function store(GroupRequest $request)
  {
    $result = $this->group_service->createGroupWith($request->all());

    return redirect()->back()->with('message', $result['msg']);
  }
 
  public function update(GroupRequest $request, Group $group)
  {
    $result = $this->group_service->updateAGroupWith($request->all(), $group);

    return redirect()->back()->with('message', $result['msg']);
  }
}
```

And bellow is my service

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use App\Models\Group;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class GroupsService
{
  public function listAll()
  {
    $groups = Group::all();

    return $groups;
  }

  public function createGroupWith($data)
  {
    try {
      DB::beginTransaction();

      $modules_id = array_pop($data);

      $group = Group::create($data);
      $group->modules()->attach($modules_id);

      DB::commit();
      return ['msg' => 'Grupo criado com sucesso!'];
    } catch (\Throwable $error) {
      DB::rollBack();
      return ['msg' => $error->getMessage()];
    }
  }

  public function updateAGroupWith($data, $group)
  {
    try {
      DB::beginTransaction();

      $modules_ids = array_pop($data);

      $group->update($data);
      $group->modules()->sync($modules_ids);

      DB::commit();
      return ['msg' => 'O grupo foi atualizado com sucesso!'];
    } catch (\Throwable $error) {
      DB::rollBack();
      return ['msg' => $error->getMessage()];
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, my service is instanciated by Laravel on the controller's `__construct` method and is used on the rest of my methods. The problem with this is that when storing or updating a register, I need to pass the data and (for the update) the gruop I want to update. This violates Uncle Bob's ideal of zero parameters and thus my question: is there a way to solve this?

I have come up with some ideas. The first one would be to continue instanciating the service as it is already done, but having properties such as group and data defined before calling the method I want. Something as implemented bellow. In this case the problem is that if I want to be really idealistic, I don't if I can keep accessing properties from an object and changing them, I believe I'd need to instanciate the object with it's state already defined anyways.

```
public function update(GroupRequest $request, Group $group)
  {
    $this->group_service->group = $group;
    $this->group_service->data = $request->all();
    $result = $this->group_service->updateAGroup();


    return redirect()->back()->with('message', $result['msg']);
  }
```

The second ideia would be to instanciate the service as I need it on each method:

```
public function update(GroupRequest $request, Group $group)
  {
    $service = new GroupService($data, $group);
    $result = $service->updateAGroup();


    return redirect()->back()->with('message', $result['msg']);
  }
```

The only problem with the idea above is that in the fist method, the one for storing, I'd need to make the `$group` parameter for the `$service = new GroupService($data, $group);` statement optional. But I don't know if that's really a problem or a whim of mine.

And there's a third idea, but it seems way too much. It would be to make have a service per case (storing, updating and deleting maybe) and then I wouldn't have to worry with having optional parameters on the `__construct` method.

Anyways, I'd like to know your ideas, comments, and critiques too. Please take into consideration that I know this is very idealistic, but I'd really like to know how to come closer to it using with the patterns already defined on Laravel.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Although it states that the optimal number of parameters is zero, it also says that one or two are okay, too. I won't write my on personal opinion on Bob's book, but I will say that you should write code that works, first and foremost. If an intermediary abstraction (like a DTO) helps you reason about it, and cuts your parameters from 10 down to 1, great. But if you only use that abstraction for this single purpose (along with the corresponding test), consider if it is valuable to maintain that abstraction in perpetuity, too.

Comment: Following on from the solid advice of  @ChrisHaas, something to remember is that pragmatism trumps perfection. Patterns are great but often overused and blindly implemented because someone read an article somewhere saying they _should_ be using `x` to achieve `y`.

Comment: @ChrisHaas, I've thought about this a lot and I get all your points, but I'd really like to know the solutions. I mean, I've tried to do this a lot by myself but I always end up with some mess. That's why 1) I learned that it's not always the best thing to implement every pattern/advice right away, but rather start your project letting the flow take you (I am using TDD); and 2) because I ended up with some mess, I'd like to know the solution now: you know, as if I had a difficult college test and just want to know if anyone knows the answer. Thank you a lot by your answer, by the way.

Comment: @BernardoBeniniFantin, I know you are looking for an answer, but unfortunately this is very subjective. What is "a mess", exactly? Does it work? I will take a working mess any day. Instead of making a perfect start, I'd instead learn how to refactor up to a point that you think it is no longer messy. I know that's not the answer you want, but I'd estimate that's how the vast majority of programmers work. Make it work, quantify messy, clean the mess. Repeat. From that you'll learn best practices for next time.